# Chave estrangeira com mais de 1 valor

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql

estou trabalhando na construção do meu TCC e me surgiu um problema.
Eu tenho uma tabela cronograma, e essa tabela precisa armazenar alguns dados, dentre elas, as atividades que serão passadas durante o ano. Devido a isso, eu criei a tabela atividades, mas aí me surge um problema: um cronograma pode ter várias atividades, como eu posso armazenar mais de uma atividade nesse cronograma?? O valor é indefinido, um cronograma pode ter até 47 atividades, e gostaria de adicioná-las dinamicamente ao cronograma. Ou seja, a tabela atividades deve emprestar mais de uma key por vez na tabela cronograma, como fazer isso??

Answer (score 0):

O que você vai fazer é um relacionamento 1:n, o que significa que um cronograma vai ter *n* atividades.

Na prática, você precisa adicionar uma chave estrangeira na tabela de `atividades` referenciando a chave primária do seu `cronograma`.

Partindo do pressuposto que seu banco já está modelado, você pode alterar a tabela de `atividades` para ter essa chave estrangeira da seguinte forma (mude os nomes no que for necessário):

```
-- Adicionando o campo para armazenar a chave estrangeira
ALTER TABLE `atividades` ADD COLUMN `cronograma_id` INTEGER NOT NULL;

-- Configurando sua chave estrangeira
ALTER TABLE `atividades`
ADD CONSTRAINT
FOREIGN KEY(cronograma_id) -- o nome do campo que vai armazenar a chave
REFERENCES cronogramas(id); -- a referência da tabela e do campo da tabela que tem essa chave
```

Comment: Olá amigo, mas nesse caso, a criação de um cronograma depende da existência de atividades. Como eu iria definir a chave estrangeira de um cronograma em uma atividade, sendo que ainda tecnicamente não existe o cronograma, visto que a tabela atividades cadastra primeiro?

Comment: Essa lógica é estranha. Um cronograma possui `n` atividades, não o contrário. Você cria um cronograma e depois cria as atividades atrelando elas à esse cronograma."